# One iteration of forward Gauss-Seidel followed by one iteration of backward Gauss-Seidel

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $A = D - L - U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a nonsingular matrix, where $-L$ is the matrix of strictly lower triangular elements and $-U$ is the matrix of strictly upper triangular elements. Recall that the three methods:
>
> $\cdot$ Gauss-Seidel (Forward): $P_{gs} = D - L$ $$x_{k+1} = x_k + P^{-1}_{gs}r_k = x_k + (D-L)^{-1}r_k $$
>
> $\cdot$ Gauss-Seidel (Backward): $P_{bgs} = D - U$ $$x_{k+1} = x_k + P^{-1}_{bgs}r_k = x_k + (D-U)^{-1}r_k $$
>
> $\cdot$ Symmetric Gauss-Seidel: $P_{sgs} = (D - L)D^{-1}(D-U)$ $$x_{k+1} = x_k + P^{-1}_{sgs}r_k = x_k + (D-U)^{-1}D(D-L)^{-1}r_k $$
>
> Show that one iteration of Symmetric Gauss-Seidel is equivalent to one iteration of forward Gauss-Seidel followed by one iteration of backward Gauss-Seidel

Solution - We have $A = D - L - U$ and one iteration of forward Gauss-Seidel followed by one iteration of backward Gauss-Seidel is given by $$y = x_k + P^{-1}_{gs}r_k = x_k + (D-L)^{-1}r_k$$ $$r_y = b - Ay = b - A(x_k + (D-L)^{-1}r_k) = b - Ax_k - A(D-L)^{-1}r_k = r_k(I-A(D-L)^{-1})$$ Now adding this to one iteration of backward Gauss-Seidel gives is \begin{align*}x_{k+1} = y + P^{-1}_{bgs}r_y &= y + (D-U)^{-1}r_y\\
&= x_k + (D-L)^{-1}r_k + (D-U)^{-1}(r_k (I - A(D-L)^{-1})\\
&= x_k + (D-L)^{-1}r_k + (D-U)^{-1}r_k + (D-U)^{-1}A(D-L)^{-1}r_k\\
&= x_k + r_k((D-L)^{-1} + (D-U)^{-1}A(D-L)^{-1})
\end{align*}

I am not sure where to go from here any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once more and a bit less messy (without vectors dancing randomly around matrices and missing terms in the last equation):

One forward Gauss-Seidel gives
$$
x_{k+1/2}=x_k+(D-L)^{-1}r_k
$$
with the residual
$$
\begin{split}
r_{k+1/2}&=b-Ax_{k+1/2}=b-A(x_k+(D-L)^{-1}r_k)=r_k-A(D-L)^{-1}r_k
\\&=r_k-(D-L-U)(D-L)^{-1}r_k=U(D-L)^{-1}r_k.
\end{split}
$$
Then the backward Gauss-Seidel follows like
$$
\begin{split}
x_{k+1}&=x_{k+1/2}+(D-U)^{-1}r_{k+1/2}
=x_k+[(D-L)^{-1}+(D-U)^{-1}U(D-L)^{-1}]r_k
\\&=x_k+(D-U)^{-1}[(D-U)+U](D-L)^{-1}r_k
=x_k+(D-U)^{-1}D(D-L)^{-1}r_k.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Could you add more details where we have $$r_k - (D-L-U)(D-L)^{-1}r_k = U(D-L)^{-1}r_k$$ I am trying to do the algebra but I don't seem to get the result.

Comment: @Wolfy It's because $(D-L-U)(D-L)^{-1}=[(D-L)-U](D-L)^{-1}=[(D-L)(D-L)^{-1}-U(D-L)^{-1}]=I-U(D-L)^{-1}$